# comparing sub elements in a list with another

Tags: python, string, list, comparison, nlp

I have a list of sentences  `listOfSentences` that looks like this:

```
listOfSentences = ['mary had a little lamb.', 
                   'she also had a little pram.',
                   'bam bam bam she also loves ham.', 
                   'she ate the lamb.']
```

I also have a dictionary of `keywords` that looks like this:

```
keyWords= {('bam', 3), ('lamb', 2), ('ate', 1)}
```

where the higher frequency the word is the smaller the key of it in `keyWords`  .

```
>>> print(keySentences)
>>> ['bam bam bam she also loves ham.', 'she ate the lamb.',]
```

My question is: **how can I compare the elements in `keyWords` to the elements in `listOfSentences` so that I can output a list `keySentences`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyWords` is more useful if it is a dictionary, then it is a simply dictionary lookup to obtain each word's score. Each word can be extracted using `split()`.

Here is some code to do it. This assumes that punctuation is part of a word (as your example resultant list `keySentences` implies):

```
listOfSentences = ['mary had a little lamb.', 
                   'she also had a little pram.',
                   'bam bam bam she also loves ham.', 
                   'she ate the lamb.']

keyWords= [('bam', 3), ('lamb', 2), ('ate', 1)]
keyWords = dict(keyWords)

keySentences = []
for sentence in listOfSentences:
    score = sum(keyWords.get(word, 0) for word in sentence.split())
    if score > 0:
        keySentences.append((score, sentence))

keySentences = [sentence for score, sentence in sorted(keySentences, reverse=True)]
print(keySentences)
```

**Output**

```
['bam bam bam she also loves ham.', 'she ate the lamb.']
```

---

If you want to disregard punctuation you can remove it from each sentence before processing:

```
import string

# mapping to remove punctuation with str.translate()
remove_punctuation = {ord(c): None for c in string.punctuation}

listOfSentences = ['mary had a little lamb.', 
                   'she also had a little pram.',
                   'bam bam bam she also loves ham.', 
                   'she ate the lamb.']

keyWords= [('bam', 3), ('lamb', 2), ('ate', 1)]
keyWords = dict(keyWords)

keySentences = []
for sentence in listOfSentences:
    score = sum(keyWords.get(word, 0) for word in sentence.translate(remove_punctuation).split())
    if score > 0:
        keySentences.append((score, sentence))

keySentences = [sentence for score, sentence in sorted(keySentences, reverse=True)]
print(keySentences)
```

**Output**

```
['bam bam bam she also loves ham.', 'she ate the lamb.', 'mary had a little lamb.']
```

Now the resulting list also contains "mary had a little lamb." because the fullstop trailing "lamb" was removed by `str.translate()`.

Answer (score 1):

The following will score your sentences according to the matching word counts:

```
import re

keyWords = [('bam', 3), ('lamb', 2), ('ate', 1)]
keyWords = [w for w, c in keyWords]     # only need the words

listOfSentences = [
    'mary had a little lamb.', 
    'she also had a little pram.',
    'bam bam bam she also loves ham.', 
    'she ate the lamb.']    

words = [re.findall(r'(\w+)', s) for s in listOfSentences]
keySentences = []

for word_list, sentence in zip(words, listOfSentences):
    keySentences.append((len([word for word in word_list if word in keyWords]), sentence))

for count, sentence in sorted(keySentences, reverse=True):
    print '{:2}  {}'.format(count, sentence)
```

Giving you the following output:

```
 3  bam bam bam she also loves ham.
 2  she ate the lamb.
 1  mary had a little lamb.
 0  she also had a little pram
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
>>> [x for x in listOfSentences for i in keyWords if x.count(i[0])==i[1]]
['bam bam bam she also loves ham.', 'she ate the lamb.']
```

Comment: this would also match `late for ate`

Comment: OP only said for word, may be he need exact match

Comment: that is what i am saying you are doing partial match here and how did you come to this logic I cannot understand what OP is asking

Comment: This isn't what I thought the OP was asking - I *think* 'she ate the lamb' should appear in the list not because it contains 'ate' once, but because it contains both 'ate' (score 1) and 'lamb' (score 2). So the sentence "scores" 3, making it the joint highest-scoring sentence.

Comment: @user3468054 is correct, sorry for not making that clear